# Spring Boot 3 Maven Multi Module Project : Dependencies are downloaded in different versions in the repository : Hence having class not found issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PathPatternsRequestCondition.parse(PathPatternsRequestCondition.java:83)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
'java.lang.String org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPatternParser.initFullPathPattern(java.lang.String)'
```

The calling method's class, org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PathPatternsRequestCondition, was loaded from the following location:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/6.0.14/spring-webmvc-6.0.14.jar!/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/PathPatternsRequestCondition.class
```

The called method's class, org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPatternParser, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.0.9/spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPatternParser.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.0.14/spring-web-6.0.14.jar!/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPatternParser.class
```

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPatternParser: file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.0.9/spring-web-6.0.9.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PathPatternsRequestCondition and org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPatternParser